# NetBeans IDE plugin, how do I open a terminal tab?

Tags: netbeans, plugins

I'm creating a NetBeans plugin and I would like to open a terminal tab and manipulate it as if I had clicked `Window > IDE Tools > Terminal`.

I've been looking around and I can't find any documentation on how to do stuff like this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I found my own solution thankfully. Netbeans has a module called `Native Terminal`.

Upon adding a reference this module, I can access the `TerminalSupport::openTerminal` method. This will create a terminal instance.